# How to manage ACL rules?

Tags: php, design-patterns, acl

I'm writing an ACL class that takes its rules from "setter" methods:

```
<?php
$acl = new AccessControlList();
$acl->allow('someController', 'publicAction', 'guestRole');
$acl->deny('someController', 'privateAction', 'guestRole');
```

The question is: what's the best option for storing these rules in the ACL object?

At the moment, I'm considering an array like this:

```
array(
    'guest' => array(
        'someController' => array(
            'publicAction' => true,
            'privateAction' => false
        )
    ),
    'admin' => array (
        ...
    )
)
```

But it looks like it will be a performance disaster when it grows, keeping in mind the logic to read the array (infering `isAllowed(...)` results) and writing it (with rule conflicts, overwrites, inheritance between roles and resources...).

Maybe I'm wrong from the begining and those "setters" are the problem. **Is there any well established design pattern to follow?**

Comment: Have you looked at `zend_acl`? Might give you some insight

Comment: Lazy load the ACL Rules.

Comment: @AlexP In fact my implementation is a minimalistic version of `zend_acl` (if I really understood how it works). The problem is that I think all the simplification will pay the price of that messy array.

Comment: @Orangepill, that sounds well, could it inspire an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid populating the entirety of the ACL list by lazy loading.

This is a very simplistic approach but the concept should scale. This assumes that for a given request most if not all of the acl checks will be against single users role, but the same technique could be used for a controller or a combination of role and controller.

Define the acl in a tabular way (csv, json, ini, db table, or php include) whatever just so you can get, an array that contains allow or deny, action, and role. I'm going to go with a php include because it assumes the least. You would have one of these for each of the roles.

```
return array(
     array("allow", "someController", "someAction"),
     array("deny", "someController", "someOtherAction")
);
```

Add a method onto your AccessControlList to read and process such a file.

```
protected function readConfig($role, $source){
     $dat = include($source);
     foreach($dat as $rule){
          switch($rule[0]){
              case "allow": $this->allow($rule[2], $rule[3], $role); break;
              case "deny":  $this->deny($rule[2], $rule[3], $role); break; 
         }
     }
}
```

Add a method to bind an role to a file. this will simply add to your existing acl

```
public function setRules($role, $source){
    $this->acl[$role] = $source;
}
```

Then in your isAllowed check to see if the role's acl node is a string or an array

```
public function isAllowed($role, $subject, $action){
     if (is_string($this->acl[$role])){
             $this->readConfig($role, $this->acl[$role]);
     }
     // do your acl check as normal. 
}
```

Comment: If I understood, your solution relies on having independent files for each role. That's an option, of course, but you gave me the idea of storing the rules in an unique file and filter them (by role and resource) within the `readConfig` method -without a `setRules` method-. Now I think that the essence is to separate the ruleset from the ACL object, that opens many ways to select a scope from the entirety of the rules. That fits me :)